# R/VBA - Sorting data

Tags: r, vba, sorting

I am attempting to create a data set from an original dataframe (in either R or Excel VBA code), and I am trying to generate another column. Here is a high-level situation:

```
dfr <- data.frame(
    grp   = rep(c("X", "Y"), each = 4),
    id    = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "F"),
    value = c(3, 7, 2, 4, 8, 9, 11, 2)
)
```

Of the second column, B is the "leader" of both group "X" and "Y" as it has the largest numbers. Thus, I need to pair all the observations other observations in the relevant groups (X, Y) to these leaders. For example, a sample output is below of what I need:

```
X  B A 3
X  B C 2
X  B D 4
Y  B E 8
Y  B A 9
Y  B F 2
```

The number on the furthest column is the respective number of the datapoint previously found.

So, I need help partitioning the data between X and Y (for countless string groups that exist) and afterwards, sorting it in the way I need and having that column produced, either  in R-code or VBA for excel (the data is in CSV format)

**Disclaimer: If it isn't obvious, my use of R is very limited - I used it for 4 months in an Applied Econometrics course, and now am finding myself in need of it again (9months later) so please excuse me if I seem like a novice...I can run regressions just fine though :)

***UPDATE**
Following Henry's code, this is where I am now.

```
data <- read.csv(file = "sort.csv", h=T)
attach(data)
sorted <- data[order(data$membernumber, -data$dailycirc),]
top <- function(df){ return(df[1,])}
moded <- unsplit(lapply(split(sorted, sorted$membernumber), top), unique(sorted$membernumber))[1:2]
names(moded) <- c("membernumber", "cnty")
merged <- merge(moded, data, by="membernumber")
merged[merged$cnty != merged$cnty, ]
summary(merged)
```

This has actually now given me some output. But I'm not seeing the sort, just a summary statistic of things like the mean/max. How do I actually export this into a CSV or spreadsheet so I can look at it like a table?

Thank you SO much for your help.

Comment: G does not appear in your data.

Comment: Have a quick read on split-apply-combine problems.  http://4dpiecharts.com/2011/12/16/a-quick-primer-on-split-apply-combine-problems/

Comment: @ Henry, thank you for the G, I decided to make it "B" last-minute to stress that the categories X&Y can have many overlapped areas (reference A,B..etc)                                                           @Roman, unfortunately, I am still attempting to write the pseudocode and wrap my mind around it. I do not have actual code written yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only R people seem to have waken up I felt obliged to post an example in VBA. I assume that you have opened your CSV in Excel with information in the first 3 columns, no title line (data starts on row 1). You copy that 
data to a new spreadsheet, in a tab named "Sheet1". You insert the code below in a new module and run it, and it will output the result in columns 5 to 8 of the same sheet. For 10,000 lines input, it runs in less than 0.1 sec on my machine.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub doIt()

    Dim data As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim dict1 As Variant
    Dim dict2 As Variant

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    data = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        If dict1.exists(data(i, 1)) Then
            If dict2(data(i, 1)) < data(i, 3) Then
                dict1(data(i, 1)) = data(i, 2)
                dict2(data(i, 1)) = data(i, 3)
            End If
        Else
            dict1(data(i, 1)) = data(i, 2)
            dict2(data(i, 1)) = data(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim result(LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1) - dict1.Count, 1 To 4) As Variant

    j = 1
    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        If data(i, 2) <> dict1(data(i, 1)) Then
            result(j, 1) = data(i, 1)
            result(j, 2) = dict1(data(i, 1))
            result(j, 3) = data(i, 2)
            result(j, 4) = data(i, 3)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 5).Resize(UBound(result, 1), UBound(result, 2)) = result
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is much more readable code to me - I actually understand VBA! One question: I actually have 6 columns, and 10,733 rows - first row is headers. I have to deliver an output similar but also all the columns must be part of the output.

Comment: @Dman You just want to copy whatever is in the next 3 columns after the 4th column in your sample output?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `plyr` package, try

```
ddply(dfr, .(grp), transform, id.max = id[which.max(value)])
```

---

Lots of separate questions here, but it looks like you need a few pointers to get going with R.

```
data <- read.csv(file = "sort.csv", h=T)
```

Don't use `T` for `TRUE`, one day you'll declare a variable named `T` and generate a hard to find bug.  I'd also be tempted to wrtie `header` instead of `h` since it will be more obvious what the code does when you come back to it in another 9 months.

---

```
attach(data)
```

Neve use `attach`.  It's another fine source of hard to track down bugs.  Use [with](http://4dpiecharts.com/2011/04/29/friday-function-triple-bill-with-vs-within-vs-transform/) instead.

---

```
sorted <- data[order(data$membernumber, -data$dailycirc),]
```

... like this

```
sorted <- data[with(data, order(membernumber, -dailycirc)), ]
```

---

```
top <- function(df){ return(df[1,])}
```

The `head` function does this already.

---

```
moded <- unsplit(lapply(split(sorted, sorted$membernumber), top),   unique(sorted$membernumber))[1:2]
```

This is where `tapply` or `ddply` comes in.  Something like

```
moded <- with(sorted, tapply(cnty, membernumber, head, n = 1))
```

(Check this line. Since I can't reproduce your example it's hard to say exactly what it should be.)

---

```
merged[merged$cnty != merged$cnty, ]
```

Since the condition is always `FALSE`, this must return an empty data frame.  Are you sure you meant this?

---

Use `write.csv` or `writeLines` for writing things to file.

Comment: This is a great start, I'm reading the document(s) and links provided. 

    I got the following error: Error in parse(text = x) :    <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol
1: THE STAR
       ^
Would you be able to help me understand this a bit more? I feel like you put me on a great path and I just am a bit inexperienced with R to carry myself all the way.

Comment: `parse` takes a character string and tries to turn it into an R expression.  `"THE STAR ^"` isn't valid R, so you got an error.  I'm not sure how that relates to the original question though.  If you are having separate issues with `parse`, ask them in a different question.

Answer (score 1):

The following

```
sorted <- dfr[order(dfr$grp, -dfr$value), ]  
top <- function(df){ return(df[1,]) }
moded <- unsplit(lapply(split(sorted, sorted$grp), top), unique(sorted$grp))[1:2]
names(moded) <- c("grp", "leader")
merged <- merge(moded, dfr, by="grp")
merged[merged$leader != merged$id, ]
```

produces

```
  grp leader id value
1   X      B  A     3
3   X      B  C     2
4   X      B  D     4
5   Y      B  E     8
6   Y      B  A     9
8   Y      B  F     2
```

and

```
> summary(merged)
 grp   leader id        value      
 X:4   A:0    A:2   Min.   : 2.00  
 Y:4   B:8    B:2   1st Qu.: 2.75  
       C:0    C:1   Median : 5.50  
       D:0    D:1   Mean   : 5.75  
       E:0    E:1   3rd Qu.: 8.25  
       F:0    F:1   Max.   :11.00
```

Comment: Dear Henry, can you assist me in making that code translate to 10,000+ observations? Also, I don't have the R-background to see through your code and take out the high-level structure I need in order to put in my own variable names + titles.

Comment: @Dman: First line sorts by `grp` and then in reverse order by `value`; second and third lines take the first two columns of the top `value` for each `grp`; fourth line renames those columns (which were `grp` and `id`) to `grp` and `leader`; fifth line merges back with the data so each `grp` has its `leader`; sixth line removes those cases where the `leader` and `id` are the same.

Comment: @ Henry: I think I have it, now how do I create a spreadsheet with this? I tried the WriteXLS package and got this:  WriteXLS(merged, "WriteXLS.xls", perl = perl)
Error in get(x, envir = envir) : object 'integer(0)' not found

Comment: I'm actually not getting any output. When I do "summary(merged)" I get my variables but a bunch of zeroes in all my summary statistics.

Comment: @Dman: try the code with a clean start to R.  I have shown what I get with `summary`.

Comment: I will edit my current code and maybe you will spot the error. The real difference is because I am loading the data from a CSV, and you seem to be just using data initialized in dfr. And this difference is confusing me.

Comment: The real way to measure if I am doing it right would be to generate a CSV or Spreadsheet from R that does the sorting I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best solution, and someone will likely give you a better solution using the reshape package but it seems to work for your example and a few others I tried.

```
df = data.frame(c(sample(c(LETTERS), 10000,replace=T)),
                sample(LETTERS[1:5],10000,replace=T),
                runif(10000))
names(df) = c("id","grp", "value")
i = levels(df$id)[1]

groupings =  lapply(levels(df$i), function(i){
                                    d = subset(df,df$id==i)
                                    l = length(d$value[d$id==i])
                                    m = max(d$value)
                                    leader= d$grp[d$value==m]
                                    piece = data.frame(id = rep(i,l),
                                                       grp= rep(as.character(leader),l),
                                                       grp2 = d$grp,
                                                       value = d$value)

                                    })

df.final = do.call(rbind,groupings)
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I am trying to replicate this analysis on over 10,000 observations. I don't have the skill to take your code to that level!

Comment: Did you test this on 10,000 observations? 'cause it runs in less than 5 seconds. Minor problem with the lengths, I will edit to fix. Still suggest you go with one of the answers above.